# Object "SlotMachine" is not enabled for rendering

Tags: rendering, cycles-render-engine, error

I have been baking textures for some time. For the first time I got the message "Object "SlotMachine" is not enabled for rendering". There are seven slots that need to be baked. I was able to bake a simpler object in another file with the same setup.

Here is an image of the Shading for the first node. I have the output image selected. Here is an image of the shader.
[image]

Blender version information.
[image: Blender version]

OS and Machine stats.
[image: MacOS Version and machine]

In response to an answer, I simplified the file and now get "No valid selected objects" as an error. I have confirmed it is selected.

[image]

---

I simplified the file and now get "No valid selected objects" as an error. I have confirmed it is selected.

[image]

Comment: Combining everything probably didn't help because it probably messed up your UV Map.  I think it's now saying it can't find a UV map that matches the current joined object.

Comment: I redid the UV maps and still no joy. Same error.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the outliner. The collection that contains the object *SlotMachine* is disabled for rendering. This disables also all objects and sub-collections that are inside this collection.

[image: collection disabled for rendering]

For texture baking the objects that are involved must be enabled for rendering. Click the "camera"  icon right next to the collection's name to enable it.